# How do I print duplex on a P115w?

Tags: printing, duplex

I'm going to buy a new P115w printer.

With a Phaser 3155 I press the Reset button (triangle symbol) to print the other side after refilling the paper manually, however the P155w has only one button (Power).

How do I to print both sides on a P115w?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I print duplex on a P115w?

1. Choose "Multiple Page" and "2-sided/Booklet":

> [image]

2. Follow the instructions to reinsert the paper:

> [image]

3. Click "OK"

Source [DocuPrint P115 w User’s Guide](http://onlinesupport.fujixerox.com/driver_downloads/DPP115W_UG_EN.pdf)